# Swagger: Filter endpoints for admin and users

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

How can I add a filter to swagger that will filter my endpoints based on roles.

For example, if I only want to see the endpoints for the admin. Either endpoint for users, or for both of them.

We only have this option for versions, I need something similar for roles. (see [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wlrH.jpg))

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Read This Document Of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore That Answer your question

[Generate Multiple Swagger Documents](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents)

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API - V1", Version = "v1" });
    c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API - V2", Version = "v2" });
})
```

On your Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]
public void Post([FromBody]Product product)
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: The question says "We only have this option for versions, I need something similar for roles."

Comment: I did all things with documentation that you sent, but when I am try to open /swagger/v1.0/swagger.json I see only json, UI don't load, Do you know why?